# How to create serializable Dynamic Model?

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm trying to create a serializable model which will change dynamically

The serialized JSon will look like below

```
{
    "Job" : {
        "LensJobId" : "123546"
        "JobTitle"  : "Manager"
        "PostingDate" : "2013-11-20"
    }
    "Job" : {
        "LensJobId" : "3256987"
        "JobTitle"  : "Supervisor"
        "PostingDate" : "2013-11-20"
    }
}
```

Serializable Class that im currently having

```
Class Job
{
  public string lensjobid {get; set;}
  public string jobtitle{get; set;}
  public string postingdate{get; set;}
}
```

Now the new requirement is i have to include the entries inside job based on request ex: if the request asked for lensjobid and jobtitle i have to include only those or if the request asked location details like state, country etc then that should be included.

For the above req, i have come up with a solution like below

```
public class DistributionList : List<Distribution>
{

}

[DataContract]
public class Distribution
{   
    [DataMember(Name = "Job")]
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> DistributionValues { get; set; }

}
```

The serialized json output of this will be

```
  [{
            "Job" : [{
                    "Key" : "lensjobid",
                    "Value" : "124353453"
                }, {
                    "Key" : "JobTitle",
                    "Value" : "Manager"
                },
                {
                    "Key" : "PostingDate",
                    "Value" : "2012-13-11"
                }
            ]
        },
{
    "Job" : [{
                    "Key" : "lensjobid",
                    "Value" : "124353453"
                }, {
                    "Key" : "JobTitle",
                    "Value" : "Manager"
                },
                {
                    "Key" : "PostingDate",
                    "Value" : "2012-13-11"
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
```

But the above looks odd to me,is there any way i could make this look like the output of my previous approach?

Thanks and Regards!!

Comment: 1. You JSON is not valid. 2. In it's current structure (after fixing the `,`), only the last `Job` will be used by the parser. [RFC 4627 - The application/json Media Type for JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627): _The names within an object SHOULD be unique_

Answer (score 0):

Use json.net and create a contract resolver

```
public class CustomContractResolver : Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver
{
    private IEnumerable<string> propertyNames;

    public CustomContractResolver(IEnumerable<string> propertyNames)
    {
        this.propertyNames = propertyNames;
    }
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        return properties.Where(p => propertyNames.Contains(p.PropertyName)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Serialize like this

```
var jobs = getJobs();    
var contractResolver = new CustomContractResolver(new[]{ "Property1", "Property2" });

string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jobs, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,
    new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = contractResolver });
```